# Are there any plans to add Inbox functionality to SO API?

Tags: discussion, api

So, 3rd party applications will be able to notify users about new answers and comments.

Comment: See the API 2.0 [`/inbox`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) and [`/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) routes.

Answer (score 3):

API V2.0 introduced the [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) and [/inbox/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) routes.

They provide read-only access to a user's inbox, and both require [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).